# composing xsd with simpletype and complex type in one element

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to make xsd for below element at onece.
is there any idea for doing this?

```
<database>
    <user>user1</user>
    <password>dbpassword</password>
</database>


<database>"user1/password"</database>
```

so  elment can have one of complex type and simple string type.

how can I compose xsd for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `complexType` with the `mixed` attribute set to true.  From the [W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp):

> To enable character data to appear between the child-elements of "letter", the mixed attribute must be set to "true".

```
<xs:element name="database" type="dbType"/>

<xs:complexType name="dbType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The `<user>` and `<password>` tags appear optionally, meaning that the `<database>` tag can contain only a string and be valid.

You probably should just stick with one style for the username and password.  Use either simple text *or* have them in separate tags, but not both.  Mixing both together could welcome some unwanted behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixed content and make the element nodes optional, but this will probably allow a lot of things you don't want to allow.

In XSD 1.1 you can define it as mixed content and use assertions to further constrain what can appear. But that's not a particularly nice solution either, because you can't define the constraint simply as "either complex-type-1 or simple-type-2".

I would advise against doing it. For example, if the simple type is a legacy format and you want to move to the more structured form of the element, I would use a different element name, or perhaps give it an attribute format="v2" and then use XSD 1.1 conditional type assignment to assign a type based on the attribute value.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but because of backward compatiblity issue :( I can't force to change to new format...